# How to retrieve alt attribute for an attachment (uploaded image)?

Tags: attachments, media, media-library, uploads, customization

I have some IDs of attachments (images, not from current post). How to I get the alt attribute for those images?

I have tried to look into wp_get_attachment_image_src and wp_get_attachment_metadata but couldn't find the alt attribute stored in neither of those

this is where I'm looking for the alt:

```
while(the_repeater_field('featured_pics')): //this is an array of IDs
    $image_id =  get_sub_field('featured_pic'); // this function gets an individual ID from array
    $image_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('featured_pic'), 'medium');
    echo '<li class="showcase-pic"><a href="'.$image_attr[0].'" rel="lightbox">'.wp_get_attachment_image($image_id, 'thumbnail').'</a></li>'; 
endwhile;
```

Comment: Look into $image_attr by either doing print_r($image_attr) or var_dump($image_attr)

Comment: no it won't work wp_get_attachment_src contains only url, height and width of the image, not meta attributes such as title or alt unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

I haven't actually tested this, but came across the following code on my travels. Might this help?

`get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)`

Comment: no I'm sorry it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Very helpful for me on a related issue where I wanted a theme feature to work by grabbing the 'alt' attribute for an image. Thanks, @dunc!

I also found these pages in the codex to be quite helpful:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id (if you need the ID of a 'featured image')